# In app-billing takes money but wont give product

Tags: android, in-app-billing

When i call the purchase screen i can buy the in app product and everything works ok but when the user leave the app and returns to view the product it keeps asking them to buy again,

I need to know how i can make this so when the user purchases the app the store screen doesnt come up anymore and they can access the product, the app is designed so that when the user buys the app they gain access to a new activity with features built in

if anyone could help, I would be most grateful

I used this tutorial which was very helpful in getting me started:[[TUT] Simple InApp Billing / Payment By blundell](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/simple-inapp-billing-payment/)

Here is my code

```
      package com.IrishSign.app;

    import java.util.Locale;

    import com.IrishSign.app.BillingHelper;
    import com.IrishSign.app.R;
    import com.IrishSign.app.BillingService;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class IrishSignAppActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
        private static final String TAG = "BillingService";

        private Context mContext;
        private ImageView purchaseableItem;
        private Button purchaseButton;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i("BillingService", "Starting");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mContext = this;
        Button A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alphabet);
        Button purchaseableItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.topics);
        Button Intro = (Button) findViewById(R.id.intro);
        Button G = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);

        purchaseableItem.setOnClickListener(this);
        startService(new Intent(mContext, BillingService.class));
        BillingHelper.setCompletedHandler(mTransactionHandler);

        A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.IrishSign.app.alpha");
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        Intro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent("com.IrishSign.app.Intro");
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        G.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        IrishSignAppActivity.this).setCancelable(false)
                        .create(); // Reads Update
                alertDialog.setTitle("Welcome");
                alertDialog.setMessage("-----");// 

                alertDialog.setButton("Continue",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                                Intent intent5 = new Intent(
                                        IrishSignAppActivity.this,
                                        IrishSignAppActivity.class);

                            }
                        });

                alertDialog.show(); // <-- Shows dialog on screen.
            }

        });

    }

    public Handler mTransactionHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Transaction complete");
            Log.i(TAG, "Transaction status: "
                    + BillingHelper.latestPurchase.purchaseState);
            Log.i(TAG, "Item purchased is: "
                    + BillingHelper.latestPurchase.productId);

            if (BillingHelper.latestPurchase.isPurchased()) {
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.IrishSign.app.Topics");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        };

    };

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.topics:
            if (BillingHelper.isBillingSupported()) {
                BillingHelper.requestPurchase(mContext,
                        "com.blundell.item.passport");
                // android.test.purchased or android.test.canceled or
                // android.test.refunded or com.blundell.item.passport
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Can't purchase on this device");
                purchaseButton.setEnabled(false); // XXX press button before
                                                    // service started will
                                                    // disable when it shouldnt
            }

            break;
        default:
            // nada
            Log.i(TAG, "default. ID: " + v.getId());
            break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause())");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        BillingHelper.stopService();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check when the application starts by using restoreTransactions. If you have used Managed Products or Subscriptions then only you will get all the details of the user.

For Unmanaged product there is no detail maintained by google.

So call this in your main activity

```
mBillingService = new BillingService();
mBillingService.setContext(this);
mBillingService.restoreTransactions();
```

Once you call this in ResponseHandler class there is one method purchaseResponse

```
purchaseResponse(final Context context,
        final PurchaseState purchaseState, final String productId,
        final String orderId, final long purchaseTime,
        final String developerPayload, final String purchaseToken) {
 }
```

which will return all the details.

You can check purchaseState then after

```
       if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.PURCHASED) {

        } else if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.REFUNDED) {

        } else if (purchaseState == PurchaseState.CANCELED) {

        }
```